# Why does my dropdown feel so clunky?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a XAML `UserControl` embedded in a WinForms/WPF Interop `ElementHost` control. The control is pretty simple - it's just a dropdown with a button - here's the entire markup:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Rubberduck.UI.FindSymbol.FindSymbolControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Rubberduck.UI.FindSymbol"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="27" d:DesignWidth="270">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:DeclarationImageConverter x:Key="DeclarationImageConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <UserControl.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="local:FindSymbolControl.GoCommand" 
                        Executed="CommandBinding_OnExecuted"
                        CanExecute="CommandBinding_OnCanExecute"/>
    </UserControl.CommandBindings>

    <Grid>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="32" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ComboBox IsEditable="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding MatchResults}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    Text="{Binding SearchString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False"
                    IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                    TextSearch.TextPath="IdentifierName">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="local:SearchResult">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image Height="16" Width="16" Margin="2,0,2,0" Source="{Binding Declaration, Converter={StaticResource DeclarationImageConverter}}" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="2,0,2,0" Text="{Binding IdentifierName}" FontWeight="Bold" MinWidth="140" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="2,0,2,0" Text="{Binding Location}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>

        <Button Grid.Column="1"
                Command="local:FindSymbolControl.GoCommand">
            <Image Height="16" Source="pack://application:,,,/Rubberduck;component/Resources/arrow.png" />
        </Button>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The problem is that it doesn't work *reliably*, and far from *instinctively*.

- If I type something in the box that actually matches an item, nothing happens until I manually select that item in the dropdown. Like here, I typed "sleepD", the box autocompleted to "sleepDelay", but the command is still disabled:

  [image: typed "sleepD", autocompleted to "sleepDelay", but command is still disabled]
- Once I've selected the item in the dropdown, the command button gets enabled as expected (although the image on the button doesn't show up grayed-out when the button is disabled, so it's not exactly as obvious as I intended it to be).

  [image: "sleepDelay" works once it's selected from the dropdown]

  (the screenshot isn't really showing it, but there's only 1 match for that search)
- If I click the button at that point, it works as expected. The problem is that if I make a new selection from the dropdown after that, the text box gets cleared instead of displaying the item I selected, and there's a weird delay during which the box is displaying what appears to be *selected whitespace* - this only seems to happen when the previous selection was made after selecting a value in the dropdown while the search text matches multiple entries, like "Sleep" above.

  [image: wtf is this selected whitespace crap?]
- After the box got cleared, I can make a new selection from the dropdown and it will work as expected (except the VBE won't actually activate the CodePane I'm setting the selection to, but that's a separate issue).

---

The command implementation simply raises a `Navigate` event that passes a `Declaration` to the code that owns the VM instance.

The `Search` method, for which I need to add a `.Take(50)` after the `.Select`, to limit the number of returned results and perhaps reduce the lag a bit:

```
    private void Search(string value)
    {
        var lower = value.ToLowerInvariant();
        var results = _declarations.Where(
            declaration => declaration.IdentifierName.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(lower))
            .OrderBy(declaration => declaration.IdentifierName.ToLowerInvariant())
            .Select(declaration => new SearchResult(declaration));

        MatchResults = new ObservableCollection<SearchResult>(results);
    }

    private string _searchString;

    public string SearchString
    {
        get { return _searchString; }
        set
        {
            _searchString = value; 
            Search(value);
        }
    }

    private SearchResult _selectedItem;

    public SearchResult SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set 
        { 
            _selectedItem = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<SearchResult> _matchResults;

    public ObservableCollection<SearchResult> MatchResults
    {
        get { return _matchResults; }
        set { _matchResults = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

There's also an `IValueConverter` involved, that takes the `Declaration` in the `SearchResult` and `switch`es on the declaration's `DeclarationType` enum to return a pack uri that points to the .png image to use in the dropdown list.

Comment: What is the type of the objects in `MatchResults`?

Comment: Additionally, please show the implementation of the command

Comment: I verified that this isn't a problem with the element host per se. Please see a working sample [here](http://ul.to/tasdzgi3). I adapted it only minimally to remove the dependencies to the `Declaration` object.

Comment: I don't have much experience with WPF, but the default in Winforms was to bind on validation, rather than on every single keypress. Perhaps the same thing applies here? Does the dropdown work as expected if you just change focus after typing in the few characters?

Comment: @Luaan: You are right, this is the default behavior in WPF. That's why the  `, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is there, to override that default.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I've added the code for the viewmodel; the command really doesn't *do* anything but pack up the selected `Declaration` into an `EventArgs` and fire up an event - it's not the job of that viewmodel to actually navigate anywhere in the VBE. I've included the `Search` function which gets called whenever the `SearchString` changes. I suspect part of the issue is that there can be too many items in the dropdown and the converter isn't exactly the fastest way to get the .png for the `DeclarationType` of each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaah found it. It *was* all in the XAML.

Right here:

```xml
Text="{Binding SearchString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

That line doesn't belong there; binding the `TextSearch.Text` property instead...

```xml
TextSearch.Text="{Binding SearchString, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Makes it all work as intended. No glitch, no lag. Well there *is* a lag when I first drop the dropdown, but that's another issue.

Lesson learned: when `TextSearch` is enabled on an editable combobox, don't bind the `Text` property, unless you want weird behavior.